# Flutter run ends with: Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle

Tags: flutter

> Can't run my flutter project because of this error: [enter image
> description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfO4Y.png)
>
> Here my configuration: Flutter 2.5.2 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 3595343e20
> (4 weeks ago) • 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700 Engine • revision 6ac856380f
> Tools • Dart 2.14.3
>
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓]
> Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Microsoft Windows [Versione
> 10.0.22000.282], locale it-IT) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3) [✓] Chrome - develop for
> the web [✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio
> Community 2019 16.11.3) [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3) [✓]
> IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1) [✓] IntelliJ IDEA
> Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2) [✓] VS Code (version 1.61.2) [✓]
> Connected device (4 available)
>
> • No issues found!
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------------------ Gradle 7.1
>
> Build time:   2021-06-14 14:47:26 UTC Revision:
> 989ccc9952b140ee6ab88870e8a12f1b2998369e
>
> Kotlin:       1.4.31 Groovy:       3.0.7 Ant:          Apache Ant(TM)
> version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020 JVM:          1.8.0_281
> (Oracle Corporation 25.281-b09) OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
>
> I have searched for this issue but no solutions for me.
>
> Has someone more lucky than me?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
In "gradlew.bat" you have to set "JAVA_HOME" to point to your favorite JDK, probably there something wrong with JDK that is inherited from Andoid Studio intallation